# Whats ResolveAll do

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

In IOC's what does `ResolveAll` do?? I know that the offical answer is "Resolve all valid components that match this type." Does that mean that it will return any class that implements a given interface?

Comment: What does IOC stand for in this context?

Answer (score 10):

It will return all classes that were registered for a given interface.

...and are not waiting on any references to be resolved. This bit me today!

Comment: Not **precisely** true. It will return components registered with given service and any other assignable service. So if you ask for `container.ResolveAll<IController>();` it will also return services registered as `IControllerWithCache`

Comment: Also the condition you mentioned is changed in v2.5. In v2.5 Windsor will try to resolve components that are waiting for dependencies (if the dependencies are provided inline, or via say `DynamicParameters`). Only if that attempt fails it will ignore the component and move to the next one.

Answer (score 2):

With Unity, ResolveAll resolves each registered mapping for an interface **except** for the default mapping.

so if you registered:

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface, ActualClassOne>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IInterface, ActualClassOne>("Singleton", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<IInterface, ActualClassOne>("Trans", new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

ResolveAll() will only give you an IEnumerable containing a resolved "Singleton" and "Trans" mappings

Comment: Why the hell does it do that? This has always annoyed me. #Unity #Fail

Comment: Subtle encouragement not to use an unnamed mapping?

Comment: Ahem.. question was about Castle-Windsor :) Anyways, that's fairly important piece of information. Maybe consider cut&paste to some Unity-related question? I bet there's plenty

Comment: I'd rather steer people to windsor, ninject or something nice. I was stuck with prism and unity

Comment: The "except for the default mapping." part above is vitally important.  Seems a flaw in Unity, but finding this has been a massive help!

Answer (score 1):

It will return all classes that were **registered** for a given interface.

Answer (score 0):

If I have:

container.ResolveAll(new { argument = something}).Where(...)

it seems like all components of T gets instantiated with 'something' even though not all of the components full fill the where clause.... who takes care of Releasing these extra components?